# Unable to get all worksheets ranges with REST API

Tags: sharepoint-server, rest, excel-services, api

Maybe I am doing something wrong or I didn't get the way to get my data.

I tried to call:

```
curl -k --ntlm --user user:pwd
```

https://sharepoint.server/dept/_vti_bin/ExcelRest.aspx/Department/mydoc/theWorkbook.xlsx/Model/Ranges

I get a reply but I do get only 2 entries/sheets of the document, I was expecting to get all the sheets, and then being able to update cells for those sheets.

Is there a way to achieve what I want?